# SQL one-to-many join - reject row if value is present at least once in right table

Tags: sql, relational-database, inner-join

This is a rather specific issue for which I can't find the answer from existing tutorials and resources. I am trying to find relationships of audio files within our repository in order to perform triage for migration of the audio files. Ideally I want to find the Production Master files for every existing recording which will then be the source file for the migration. However, there are known examples of recordings for which no Production Master was generated. In these instances we want to be able to determine what types of files exist and what generation (Archival, Deliverable, or neither). To further complicate this, the relationships are not found within the audio files themselves but with the METS file that links them all together. In order to find this I must use a query that links three tables - TEXT_METADATA (for the METS record), OWNER_ACCESS_TO_OBJECTS (for the audio files and their designated roles and mimetypes), and RELATIONSHIP_MAP (for determining the relationship of parent and child files). METS files are parent files (B objects) and audio files are children (A objects).

So far, I have constructed this query in order to find all METS files and their related audio files based on a descriptor type of "AUDIO_SIP" (all audio-based METS files). The last line is an attempt to restrict the results based on METS records for which there is no related Production Master.

```
Select * 
from 
   REPOSITORY.TEXT_METADATA rt, 
   REPOSITORY.RELATIONSHIP_MAP rm
where 
   rt.DESCRIPTOR_TYPE='AUDIO_SIP' and 
   rm.B_OBJECT_ID=rt.OBJECT_ID and
   rm.A_OBJECT_ID in (select ro.OBJECT_ID 
                      from REPOSITORY.OWNER_ACCESS_TO_OBJECTS ro 
                      where ro.ROLE<>'PRODUCTION_MASTER)
```

Of course, the problem here is that it returns a row for which there is no Production Master regardless of its relationship to a METS file, so this is useless. I am absolutely stumped on how to proceed to say "return all B_OBJECT_IDS and associated A_OBJECT_IDS for which there is NO Production Master linked to the B_OBJECT_ID). Make sense? Please let me know if I need to clarify. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to learn about outer joins http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  A `LEFT JOIN` would return all records from `A` LEFT JOIN `B` and only records from B that match. a FULL Outer join would return all records from A and B and those that match.  a Right join would return only records from A that match records in B... and all of B records.  If you're looking for specific help I would need to see an example with data and expected results.  You may need a self join here... I'm don't fully understand the problem yet.

Comment: You are sort of on the right track, but you want `WHERE NOT IN (...)` rather than what you have now.  Think of it as "where there aren't _any_ ..." as opposed to "where it isn't ..."

Comment: Thanks Joel! Are you saying it should say:
...
where rt.DESCRIPTOR_TYPE='AUDIO_SIP' and rm.B_OBJECT_ID=rt.OBJECT_ID 
and rm.A_OBJECT_ID not in (select ro.OBJECT_ID from REPOSITORY.OWNER_ACCESS_TO_OBJECTS ro where ro.ROLE='PRODUCTION_MASTER')

This still returns results where every A_OBJECT that is NOT a Production Master is returned. Whereas if you are suggesting it should say
Select * from REPOSITORY.TEXT_METADATA rt, REPOSITORY.RELATIONSHIP_MAP rm 
where NOT IN rt.DESCRIPTOR_TYPE='AUDIO_SIP' and rm.B_OBJECT_ID=rt.OBJECT_ID 

Wouldn't that then also exclude the audio METS? 
...